# Уведомление об изменение в БД MS SQL в ПО

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Мне необходимо реализовать функционал отслеживания изменения в БД и согласно этого изменения действовать дальше. Изменения будут вида 1/0. На данный момент, кроме использования таймера каждые 10-30 секунд(это максимум) и `SELECT` в проверяемое поле, ничего придумать не могу. Подскажите пожалуйста способ, если он существует, что бы БД оповестила об изменение и только тогда я обратился к ней и взял что мне нужно. Проект создан на `WinForms`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете подписаться на сообщения sql broker-а Об этом можно [почитать здесь](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Service-Broker-Message-e81c4316)

уже есть готовые решения помогающие не создавать велосипеды, к примеру [посмотрите на проект](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener)

Comment: Реализуется с помощью класса SqlDependency (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, реализовал.